# Custom Non Rectangular Buttons Triangular shape

Tags: iphone, xcode

I want to use triangle type buttons on image but i am unable to do this...

How to do this?

Comment: Be a bit more specific. Are you using a `UIButton` object? Created in code, or in XCode's interface editor? Do you have the desired button shape ready as an image file?

Comment: Do you mean visual shape or hit-testing region? Note that a button looking like a triangle can actually be a rectangle button with a triangular image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [project](https://github.com/ole/OBShapedButton) can help you. you can customize the shape of the `UIButton`.

Comment: Thank You very Much For Ur Project.....  I Finally Succeeded what i wanted for a long.... Thank You very much For d gr8 help....

Comment: First if all, it's not my project, i was in a situation like you are and i've search the web for a solution, i've found this project and it's amazing. thank you for the comment, and if you find my answer satisfied, you can mark it as the correct answer, and you can thumb up it too.

Answer (score 0):

All UIViews - *all of them* - are rectangles. You cannot make a UIView that is a triangle, but you *can* make one that contains and presents a triangular shape and responds only to touches within that shape. You must understand of course that underneath it all, it's a rectangle, and you'll have to handle the case wherein the user touches outside of the triangle but inside of the rectangle, probably by passing such events through to views below. Indeed, you might have to handle all touch event combinations (touch down inside, touch up outside, touch move outside, etc) in this way.

Maybe the project referenced above will handle all this, I didn't look too deeply.